# Trouble following Encrypted Big-Query tutorial document

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I wanted to try out the encrypted big query client for google big query and I've been having some trouble.

I'm following the instructions outlined in this PDF:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-WB8hYCrhZ6cmxfWFpBci1lOVE/edit

I get to the point where I'm running this command:

```
ebq load --master_key_filename="key_file" testdataset.cars cars.csv cars.schema
```

And I'm getting an error string which ends with:

```
raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
```

I've tried a few different formats for my .csv and .schema files but none have worked.  Here are my latest versions.

cars.schema:

```
[{"name": "Year", "type": "integer", "mode": "required", "encrypt": "none"}
{"name": "Make", "type": "string", "mode": "required", "encrypt": "pseudonym"}
{"name": "Model", "type": "string", "mode": "required", "encrypt": "probabilistic_searchwords"}
{"name": "Description", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable", "encrypt": "searchwords"}
{"name": "Website", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable", "encrypt": "searchwords","searchwords_separator": "/"}
{"name": "Price", "type": "float", "mode": "required", "encrypt": "probabilistic"}
{"name": "Invoice_Price", "type": "integer", "mode": "required", "encrypt": "homomorphic"}
{"name": "Holdback_Percentage", "type": "float", "mode": "required", "encrypt":"homomorphic"}]
```

cars.csv:

```
1997,Ford,E350, "ac\xc4a\x87, abs, moon","www.ford.com",3000.00,2000,1.2
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition""","","www.cheverolet.com",4900.00,3800,2.3
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition, Very Large""","","www.chevrolet.com",5000.00,4300,1.9
1996,Jeep,Grand Cherokee,"MUST SELL! air, moon roof,loaded","www.chrysler.com/jeep/grand­cherokee",4799.00,3950,2.4
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue may be that you need to move the `--master_key_filename` argument before the `load` argument. If that doesn't work, can you send the output of adding `--apilog=-` as the first argument?

Also, there is an example script file of running ebq here:
https://code.google.com/p/bigquery-e2e/source/browse/#git%2Fsamples%2Fch13

Comment: unfortunately moving the --master_key_filename argument didn't work.  When I add the --apilog flag to the start of the same command I receive this message:  FATAL Command testdataset.cars unknown

Comment: Try adding commas to the end of the lines in the schema file.